# Show a div if dynamic created span class is present on page

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

Have a site that has limited access to source code to edit.  It dynamically creates a span class

```
<span class="img-flag-label img-flag-clearance">
    <span>Clearance</span>
</span>.
```

What I need is to show a div i have set to hidden saying price displayed may be open box unit.  This is what I have...

```
jQuery $(window).on('load', function(){
    clearance = $("#isclearance");  
    if($('.img-flag-label .img-flag-clearance').is(':visible')){
        clearance.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: $("#ID").length will give you how many exist on the page, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Stated previously, $('#ID').length will give you all elements. so:

```
if($('.img-flag-label').length >= 1){ clearance.show() }
```

Make sure your script is running after the element is or is not dynamically added. 'Dynamically' might happen server-side or client-side. If it's a client-side script it could be invoked after the page is loaded.

I also take it hidden means 
`#isclearance {display: none}` because $.show() operates on the css display attr

EDIT: also you need to declare your variable `clearance` with `var, let, const` etc if this is the only code you have so far.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and this is well above my pay grade and really appreciate it. `code`jQuery $(document).ready(function(){
     var clearance = $("#isclearance");  
    if($('span.img-flag-label.img-flag-clearance').length >= 1){
        clearance.show();
    }
});' I don't think I can just use .img-flag-label as there are many created under that same class that I don't want to display the hidden div, but you know more than I.  Tried above and still nothing.